# Error with TP-link TL-Wn723n driver and 'sudo make install'

Tags: linux, debian, drivers

First I have problem with both these command:

```
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Because when I try to install Linux header its show error but after a hard trying I installed it!

Now `sudo make` works but when I run `sudo make install` I get the following error:

```
shahab@home:~$ cd rtl8188eu-master
shahab@home:~/rtl8188eu-master$ sudo make
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.9.0-7-amd64/build M=/home/shahab/rtl8188eu-master  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.0-7-amd64'
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.0-7-amd64'

shahab@home:~/rtl8188eu-master$ sudo make install
install -p -m 644 8188eu.ko  /lib/modules/4.9.0-7-amd64/kernel/drivers/net/wireless
cp rtl8188eufw.bin /lib/firmware/.
cp: cannot create regular file '/lib/firmware/.': No such file or directory
Makefile:157: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 1

shahab@home:~/rtl8188eu-master$ su
Password: 

root@home:/home/shahab/rtl8188eu-master# make && make install
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.9.0-7-amd64/build M=/home/shahab/rtl8188eu-master  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.0-7-amd64'
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.0-7-amd64'
install -p -m 644 8188eu.ko  /lib/modules/4.9.0-7-amd64/kernel/drivers/net/wireless
cp rtl8188eufw.bin /lib/firmware/.
cp: cannot create regular file '/lib/firmware/.': No such file or directory
Makefile:157: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 1
root@home:/home/shahab/rtl8188eu-master#
```

how can I done that?

> edit:

**lsusb output:**

```
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 8087:8002 Intel Corp. 
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 8087:800a Intel Corp. 
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 045b:0210 Hitachi, Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 045b:0210 Hitachi, Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 04e8:6864 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9070 (network tethering, USB debugging enabled)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 045b:0209 Hitachi, Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 045b:0209 Hitachi, Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 09da:054f A4Tech Co., Ltd. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**uname -a:**

```
Linux home 4.9.0-7-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.110-3+deb9u2 (2018-08-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**sources.list:**

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#                   OFFICIAL DEBIAN REPOS                    
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main
# deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main
# deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main
# deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main

# non-free
# deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free
# deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free

# deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
# deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free

# deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free
# deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free
```

> **result after last solution:**

[image: terminal result]

if network manager show device as **not ready** it needs a reboot!
now everything **alright!!!**

> **final result**

[image: final result]

Comment: for `kernel 5.1*` use [this repository:](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu#rtl8188eu) and [this SO question:](https://askubuntu.com/questions/904545/networkmanager-doesnt-show-ethernet-connection). Dont forget to `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager`

Comment: Also [this repo](https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8188eus) with `monitor mode` and `injection`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` as follows:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free
```

upgrade your system :

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Reboot then install the `linux-headers` , `dkms` and `firmware-realtek` :

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r) dkms firmware-realtek
```

Get the source from [this git repository](https://github.com/quickreflex/rtl8188eus).

```
git clone https://github.com/quickreflex/rtl8188eus.git 
sudo cp -R rtl8188eus/ /usr/src
cd /usr/src/rtl8188eus
sudo dkms add .
sudo dkms build 8188eu/1.0
sudo dkms install 8188eu/1.0
```

Comment: its echo following error after command ' **sudo make install** ' : '                **install -p -m 644 8188eu.ko  /lib/modules/4.9.0-7-amd64/kernel/drivers/net/wireless
cp rtl8188eufw.bin /lib/firmware/.
cp: cannot create regular file '/lib/firmware/.': No such file or directory
Makefile:157: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 1** '

Comment: also if its needed to know, when I add non-free after any of three repository in sources.list and rn apt update an error echo: **package configured multiple times**

Comment: but **DKMS** way doesnt echo any error and say complete for any command

Comment: Sorry for many comments! After **DKMS** wsy it was installed and my wifi detected also wifi icon added to the network page but not any networks detect I cant add manualy too. My chipset 8188su not 8188eu

Comment: please help me to install this package **https://goo.gl/E14Tzi** using **DKMS** if possible because I think **RTL8712** will work with **RTL8188SU**

Comment: @Shahabodinsedighouraee Welcome , please connect the USB wifi then update your question by adding the output of `lsusb` , `uname -a` and `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: question updated!

Comment: Recently I installed lxde and its network manager show under wifi option: **device not ready**

Comment: **new update of result!** terminal echo: **already built and installed for kernel**

Comment: many thanks and sorry! after I reboot everything alright!!!!!!! many thanks!

Comment: only one question left: **if driver already installed what problem was? is it about firmware-realtek not installed?**

Comment: @ShahabOuraie [montinned here](https://wiki.debian.org/rtl819x) *Non-free firmware is required for all drivers, which can be provided by installing the firmware-realtek package.*